# state-of-the-art methods to obtain SNVs from circulating tumor DNA?

Tags: snv

What is the state-of-the-art to obtain SNVs from circulating tumor DNA after Illumina sequencing? This is, finding a list of nucleotide locations that show tumour SNVs filtered out of any germline polymorphisms.

Found so far:

- [SiNVICT: ultra-sensitive detection of single nucleotide variants and
  indels in circulating tumour DNA.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27531099)
- [OpenGene/ctdna-pipeline](https://github.com/OpenGene/ctdna-pipeline)
- [MAGERI](https://github.com/mikessh/mageri): [article](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1005480)
- [MuTect](https://github.com/broadinstitute/mutect): running it against a synthetic normal for unmatched cfDNA samples that don't have normal, then filtering for 1000G germline mutations.
- [CaVEMan](https://github.com/cancerit/CaVEMan): running it against a reference normal for unmatched cfDNA samples that don't have equivalent normal, then filtering for 1000G germline mutations.
- [ShearWater](http://bioconductor.org/packages/ShearWater): [corrects against germline mutations by training against a set of healthy normal samples.](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/deepSNV/inst/doc/shearwaterML.html)

Comment: Do you think you can narrow a bit more? In what aspects are you interested? What tool(s) have you tried?

Comment: @Llopis I have now extended the question and added 3 more pieces of software that I found relevant.

Comment: Yes, precisely because you can grow the list *ad infinitum* I wanted you to narrow the question. In general those open ended questions don't work well in the StackExchange format because they don't have an answerable with a correct answer. And tend to results in a list of software, that although interesting and useful it might fit better for a blog or other type of resources. That's why I asked if you have some problem with any of these tools.

Comment: The problem is that, presumably, all of these are "state of the art", so choosing one will be largely a question of opinion. Therefore, this is a very interesting discussion, but not really something that can be given a definitive answer of the sort that the Stack Exchange model requires.